# Requiring incoming tenants to purchase furniture during a lease transfer?

Tags: rent, sublease, sale-of-goods

I've been renting in Toronto, Canada for several years now. Over those years, rent prices have skyrocketed (my current rent is about half of my new neighbors' rent who has a nearly identical unit). I am moving out soon and considering offering a lease transfer with the condition that the new tenant must buy my furniture. My furniture is not worth much but, given that my apartment will be highly desirable, I believe I can sell it for a huge profit. Is this legal?

Comment: I assume you are not the property owner here.  So the first question is does your current lease with the owner or management company allow for you do transfer your lease?  If it does, then is what you propose allowed under both the terms of that lease and any applicable laws in your jurisdiction?

Comment: @jwh20 Yes, I am the renter and yes, my lease allows for lease transfer. My proposition does not disobey any rules explicitly written in my lease. I am unsure if it is allowed under local/provincial law, hence my asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why complicate things - just sell the lease

Assuming that you are allowed by the terms of the lease to transfer it, you can negotiate whatever price from the incoming tenant that you can.

Comment: Fantastic! I was hoping this was the case, just wanted to make sure I wasn't crossing any lines. Thank you for your answer.